# Get a preamble in index with makeindex

Tags: indexing, subdividing

First of all, I'm not very good with Ubuntu, and only ok with `LaTeX`.

I'm currently finishing to write my thesis, and have one big question. I made two indices using `multind`. But I can't figure out how to write a preamble to the index, i.e. something between the title `Index` and the beginning of the indexation.

I tried to install idxlayout, and imakeidx, but both of them do not work. I should somehow get new packages, but installing them in mu current tex folder do not work, and I don't know how to proceed in another way

So : Does anyone know how to write a preamble in `multind` ? I can give a MWE but I don't think this would help in this case ...

```
 \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{splitidx} 
    \makeindex 
    \newindex[General Index]{idx} 
    \newindex[Index of Animals]{ani} 
    \newindex[Index of Fruits]{fru} 
    \newindex[Index of Vegetables]{veg} % ... 4th index 

    \begin{document} 
Apples\sindex[fru]{apple} and oranges\sindex[fru]{orange} are fruits\sindex{fruits}. 
Tomatoes\sindex[veg]{tomato} are vegetables\index{vegetables}. 
Cats\sindex[ani]{cat} are animals\sindex[idx]{animals}. 
    \printindex* 
    \end{document}
```

After this, when I run "splitidx.pl" as indicated, it's just not found ...

I works perfectly now !

It still have one question left : My text is something like 600 pages, with thousands of index references, and I fear a simple replacement of \index{} by \sindex[] could destroy stuff. I saw in another answer you made that you suggested :

```
\let\imkiindex\index
\renewcommand\index[1]{\imkiindex[#1]}
```

but that would only affect the "[]" -> "{}" and not the sindex part ? Would this work :

```
\let\imkiindex\index
\renewcommand\sindex[1]{\imkiindex[#1]} ?
```

Comment: The package `idxlayout` allows for index prologues; `imakeidx` both for multiple indices and index prologues. Try providing a MWE anyway.

Comment: Please, edit your question, rather than adding code in the comments

Comment: The script to call is `splitindex`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I had no idea I needed that ... Kile is currently downloading and installing some 207 mb. I tell you ASAP if this works ...

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to add prologues. One that works with the `splitidx` package is to slightly change the definition of the `theindex` environment for accommodating the prologue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitidx}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
 {\if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \twocolumn[\section*{\indexname}%
    %%% ADDED
    \this@index@prologue\global\let\this@index@prologue\relax
    %%%
    ]%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
          {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \columnseprule \z@
  \columnsep 35\p@
  \let\item\@idxitem}
 {\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand{\indexprologue}[1]{\gdef\this@index@prologue{#1\par\bigskip}}
\let\this@index@prologue\relax
\makeatletter

\makeindex 
\newindex[General Index]{idx} 
\newindex[Index of Animals]{ani} 
\newindex[Index of Fruits]{fru} 
\newindex[Index of Vegetables]{veg} % ... 4th index 

\begin{document} 

Apples\sindex[fru]{apple} and oranges\sindex[fru]{orange} are fruits\sindex{fruits}. 
Tomatoes\sindex[veg]{tomato} are vegetables\index{vegetables}. 
Cats\sindex[ani]{cat} are animals\sindex[idx]{animals}. 

\indexprologue{General index}
\printindex[idx]

\indexprologue{This is the index of animals}
\printindex[ani]

\indexprologue{This is the index of fruits}
\printindex[fru]

\printindex[veg] % no prologue for vegetables

\end{document}
```

If you compile this with `pdflatex`, run the `splitindex` program and then rerun `pdflatex`, you'll have the prologues in the first three indices, but not in the fourth.

Comment: Thank you, it works just great ! It still have one question left. My text is something like 600 pages, with thousands of index references, and I fear a simple replacement of \index{} by \sindex[] could destroy stuff. I saw in another answer you made that you suggested : 

\let\imkiindex\index
\renewcommand\index[1]{\imkiindex[#1]}

but that would only affect the "[]" -> "{}" and not the sindex part ? Would this work :

\let\imkiindex\index
\renewcommand\sindex[1]{\imkiindex[#1]} ?

Comment: @ThomsMorel I'd go with `\sindex`.

Comment: I'll follow your advice, and write back when it's done ! Once again, thanks.

Comment: Ok, everything is fine, I even managed to add some space in the prologue, and add both indices in the ToC. Thank you @egreg